# Twenty Eleven home page show only excerpt

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I am using the brand new twenty eleven theme, my home page is set to show latest posts, but it displays the entire posts,

I want to only show the excerpts, not the entire content,

Here is the index.php code

```
<div id="content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-0 -->

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template you're actually after is "content.php"

You'll want to change this line:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note the change of `the_content()` to `the_excerpt()`

Comment: wont that change the display for all pages and single posts to excerpt only ???

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the `<!--more-->` tag to mark up to what point your posts should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

'' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '', 'after' => '' ) ); ?>

I did the same, but while I click on listed post, it should display full post, 
but currently it is showing me excerpt rather than full post on single post page.

Answer (score -1):

solved the issue, please have a look on this:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/twenty-eleven-display-excerpt-in-tag-category-and-date-archives

Comment: thanks for your update, but this question is already solved and second thing, you are posting 2 answers, never post 2 answers, instead edit your previous answer