# Excerpt Now Showing on the Post Page

Tags: pages

I followed the excepted answer to this question ([Twenty Eleven home page show only excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22123/twenty-eleven-home-page-show-only-excerpt)) to a tee.  And it worked just like I hoped for the *main* page.  But now when I click on the blog post and go to the *post's* page, it also only has the excerpt.

How can I make this change so that the excerpt shows only on the main page, but the full blog article on the actual post's page?

My blog is located at http://sqlsalt.com for reference.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing a bit but based on your description, you probably only have an `index.php` file running both of those pages. If you create a `single.php` file in the theme that (probably) matches what you had in the `index.php` before you edited it, you should have what you want.

WordPress will look in the theme [for files of particular names](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail) to display content. Ultimately, if no specialized files are found, `index.php` will be used to display most everything. I think that is what happening in your case.

### Another approach

Edit `content.php` and change the call to `the_excerpt` to

```
if (is_singular()) {
  the_content(); // there may be parameters in your existing code
} else {
  the_excerpt(); // there may be parameters in your existing code
}
```

Unless you have something like `content-single.php` in which case you will need to look in that file but it sounds like the same `content.php` is being used.

Comment: So basically go to the theme's directory (wp-content) and create a `single.php` file, copy the contents from `index.php`, and then just modify that one div's class?

Comment: It isn't the class that matters. It is changing `the_content` to `the_excerpt`. You want `the_content` to get the full post display. That is even noted as the significant change in the accepted answer to the original question.

Comment: But that call is in the `content.php` file.  Are you saying to still have that change there?  I would have thought I *wouldn't* want to make that change in `content.php`.  Just use the `entry-summary` class for `index.php` and `entry-content` for `single.php`...?  I must be missing something if that isn't correct.

Comment: Changing the class name won't help you. The class name has nothing to do with what PHP outputs. `the_excerpt` and `the_content` _output_ different things. See the edit.